# Is there a way to prevent my use of my Mac during certain hours?

Tags: macos, parental-controls

For instance by not being able to login between 7pm and 7am.

That is for myself, for my own user account on my Mac.

I'd like to make sure I can't use my Mac during night time.

I'm using macOS 10.14.6.

Comment: you can't create a lock for yourself when you have the key. Ask people around you to lock it for you.

Comment: Thanks ankii! Your comment makes sense. I'll look into parental controls.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing on your Mac that you wouldn't want to be doing, but as far as I know there's no way to restrict login entirely.

You could, however, make it impossible to use the Internet on your Mac, which (at least for me) would dramatically reduce the likelihood that I was going to try to use it.

One such app for this is called (rather ironically) [Self Control](https://selfcontrolapp.com).

The only downside is that I believe you would have to set it every day. Maybe someone else will have a better idea.

Comment: Thanks. I already use SelfControl. At night I want to prevent any use of my Mac, not only website access. I'll look into parental control.

Comment: I do have another idea. Are you comfortable using the command line (Terminal.app)  if given instructions?

Comment: I am comfortable using the command line.